# iFrame onload not getting called when a Form Downloads a file with target as this iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

I have a iFrame as follows

```
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" onload="hideProgress();" src="hiddenFarme.html" id="hiddenFrame" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

This iframe is used as a target when I am submitting a from which downloads a PDF document

```
<form id="pdfManualForm" method="POST" target="hiddenFrame">
        <input type="hidden" name="x-auth-token" id="x-auth-token-Hidden">
        <input type="hidden" name="userName" id="userNameHidden">           
</form>
```

Function that submits the form :

```
function generatePDGManual(){
    $("#x-auth-token").val('abc');
    $("#userName").val('abc');

    $('#pdfManualForm').attr('action',  Settings.URL + "/json/manual/create")
    $("#pdfManualForm").submit();
}
```

The hide progress function looks like this :

```
function hideProgress(){
    Ajax.hideProgress();
}
```

The problem I am facing is when the form submit is complete and we receive the pdf document, hideProgress function doesn't get invoked (**on Chrome**). Is there a way I can capture the event when document download is complete.

Thanks,
Tarun

Comment: instead of a form submission...maybe an ajax call...so then you know when the call is done

Comment: I tried ajax call using this example: https://blog.jayway.com/2017/07/13/open-pdf-downloaded-api-javascript/ it loads a blank document. I believe something bad is happening when createObjectURL(blob) is called, the resultant document is twice in size.